# Dynamically creating webpage using PHP to pass variables via URL

Tags: php, url, variables

addarticle.html.php

```
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
        <li>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                <a href="?viewarticle?id=<?php echo'$id' ?>">
                <?php echo htmlout($article['id']);?>
                <?php echo htmlout($article['summary']);?>
                </a>

                </div>
            </form>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

index.php

```
    if(isset($_GET['viewarticle']))
    {
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ArticleManager/Includes/db.inc.php';
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);

    // Get articles belonging to author
    $sql = "SELECT summary FROM articles WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if (!result)
    {
        $error = 'Error getting full article.';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
        include 'fullarticle.html.php';
        exit();
    }
```

fullarticle.html.php

```
       <form action="" method="post">
        <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>

                <div>
                    <?php echo htmlout($article[$id]['id']);?>
                    <?php echo htmlout($article[$id]['summary']);?>

                </div>
       </form>
```

The following is a article application has a user click on a specific headline(from addarticle.html.php) and dynamically create a new page with the full article being displayed to read. I am having trouble passing the variable from the aforementioned page to the fullarticle.html.php page. Any ideas on how to correctly get the app to dynamically create a new page loading the specific article information from the database after

```
<a href="?viewarticle?id=<?php echo'$id' ?>">
```

is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm assuming that the "fullarticle" is just one article, so you wouldn't need to have a `foreach()` in that template.

Second, you're pulling out the data using a mysqli_query, so your values should be in:

```
$articleData = $result->fetch_object()
```

Then:

```
$articleData['id']
$articleData['summary']
```

Additionally, in your `mysqli_real_escape_string` call, you're using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` to get the ID value, fix that.

Comment: I formatted your answer a bit. Find here the [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for the future, its quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

OMG!

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <li>
```

Why the constant swapping in and out of PHP - it's messy and makes the code hard to debug / read.

```
        <form action="" method="post">
```

Why POST when you send the paramters via a GET, indeed there's no way to submit the form?

```
            <div>
            <a href="?viewarticle?id=<?php echo'$id' ?>">
```

$id? What $id? Conventionally '?' marks the start of the query but subsequent experssions are delimited by '&'. You seem to be parsing the viewarticle parameter in index.php - but neither the href nor the form send the data there.

```
            <?php echo htmlout($article['id']);?>
```

What does htmlout() do? Why on a seperate line of PHP? Why close and eropen the PHP tags?

```
            <?php echo htmlout($article['summary']);?>
```

And again!

```
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Assuming the mystery variable is actually $article['id']...

```
<?php 
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    print "<li><a href='/?viewarticle&id=" . $article['id']
      . "'>" . htmlout($article['id'])
      . htmlout($article['summary'])
      . "</a></li>\n";
}
?>
```

The rest of your code is also confused about how html works and how php arrays work.